# POSIX catch newline in case statement

Tags: posix, newlines, case

I want to catch if a variable is multiline in a  case statement in POSIX shell (dash).

I tried this:

```
q='
'
case "$q" in
    *$'\n'*) echo nl;;
    *) echo NO nl;;
esac
```

It returns `nl` in zsh but `NO nl` in dash.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `dash` shell does not have C-strings (`$'...'`).  C-strings is an extension to the POSIX standard. You would have to use a literal newline.  This is easier (and looks nicer) if you store the newline in a variable:

```sh
#!/bin/dash

nl='
'

for string; do

    case $string in
        *"$nl"*)
            printf '"%s" contains newline\n' "$string"
            ;;
        *)
            printf '"%s" does not contain newline\n' "$string"
    esac

done
```

For each command line argument given to the script, this detects whether it contains a newline or not.  The variable used in the `case` statement (`$string`) does not need quoting, and the `;;` after the last `case` label is not needed.

Testing (from an interactive `zsh` shell, which is where the `dquote>` secondary prompt comes from):

```
$ dash script.sh "hello world" "hello
dquote> world"
"hello world" does not contain newline
"hello
world" contains newline
```

Comment: `$nl` doesn't need quoting in the `case` statement, but it would if it contained wildcards. While `;;` is optional immediately before `esac`, omitting it makes maintenance harder because you have to remember to add it if you add another case, so I recommend always including it.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Yes, the `$nl` should be quoted (now fixed), but  using or not using `;;` before `esac` is clearly a matter of taste.

Comment: Another idea for the initializing the `$nl` constant:  `nl=$(printf "\nx") && nl=${nl%x}`.  That makes it a bit more obvious what's actually in `$nl` (does it include tabs, spaces, etc.?).

Answer (score 2):

You can include a literal newline (in quotes) as the pattern, just as you did in assigning to the variable:

```
q='
'
case "$q" in
    *'
'*) echo nl;;
    *) echo NO nl;;
esac
```

This makes the formatting ugly (you *cannot* indent the end quote), but should be fully portable. I tested in bash, zsh, ksh, and dash.